# VS2015 can't build Windows Phone Silverlight app

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I have an old Siverlight Windows Phone 8.1 Project who I tried to build today. Unfortunately there where this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       File 'MakePri.exe' not found. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12560&pver=1.0&plcid=0x409&ar=MSDN&sar=PlatformMultiTargeting&o1=Windows%20Phone&o2=8.1 for more information. SleepTracker
```

The code worked before, so no Idea what this might cause.

I use VS2015 with update 1. Also tried VS2013 without success..

Any idea?

Comment: This can often be solved with a Clean. You've tried that?

Comment: Restart Visual Studio, make a rebuild and build again.

Comment: Unfortunately both didn't work. Also deleted the obj and bin folders, without success either.

Comment: Double check and make sure you're using the correct version of the SDK in the MakePriExeFullPath path.